# Split and add space

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to parse argument inputs in a C# console application.
Where my input can be something like `a1000b2000.00c3000s321a`, so I need to format it into a list such as

```
Index 0 a 1000

Index 1 b 2000.00

Index 2 c 3000

Index 3 s321

Index 4 a
```

Here is something that I put together, but can't seem to find a way to add a space between the `a` and `100`0 and eliminate the redundant empty indexes in the list.

```
string data = "a1000b2000.00c3000s321a";

foreach (string matchdataFormat in Regex.Split(data,@"([a-z]\d*\.?\d*)"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", matchdataFormat);
        }
```

yields

```
''

'a1000'

''

'b2000.00'

''

'c3000'

''

's321'

''

'a'

''
```

Where am I going wrong here?  Thanks In-Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that split is the actual process, for it appears that to achieve the *proper* results, one should simply extract using regex.

I recommend creating a pattern to match the *internal pattern* of section letter then value, then extract into entities. Here is an example to get you started.

```
var text = "a1000b2000.00c3000s321a";

var pattern = @"(?<Section>[a-z])(?<Numbers>[\d.]*)";

var entities =
         Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
              .OfType<Match>()
              .Select((mt, index) => new
                {
                    Index   = index,
                    Section = mt.Groups["Section"].Value,
                    Value   = mt.Groups["Numbers"].Value,
                });
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: this answer is fascinating!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary +1 to your answer for the OP is stating that request and you provided it. :-)  But I surmise that he really needs the values simply split out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Spliting with regex get Match groups:

```
string data = "a1000b2000.00c3000s321a";
var matchdataFormat = new Regex(@"([a-z]\d*\.?\d*)").Matches(data);

for (int i = 0; i < matchdataFormat.Count; i++)
{
    var match = matchdataFormat[i];
    Console.WriteLine("Index {0} :  {1}", i, Regex.Replace(match.ToString(), @"(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)", "  "));
}
```

You can make spaces with another Regex which adds space between word and digit.

Comment: This seems to work, but is there a shortcut to add a space between the a and 1000.  For example 'a 1000'?

Comment: @user1440099 you could use capture groups to try to make it easier to split the match up, but there isn't anything in regular expressions themselves that do the substitution or string manipulation.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know.  I wasn't sure if there was a shortcut to handle the expression, then perform a split.  Sounds like there isn't a feature like this one yet.

Comment: @user1440099 you can do it with another regex. see edit

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank You very much.

Comment: @user1440099 take a look at OmegaMan answer. seems very clean.i think thats what you need. i would accept that one instead! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to get the position to split on:

```
(?!^)(?=[a-zA-Z]\d?)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rF2wL5/2)

Answer (score -1):

I am not certain that you don't have a typo in your spec above, but assuming that you are trying to parse the string into `a` and `1234` components, and that `s321` isn't what you want (if it is, then you need to be explicit about how many tokens that follow the first pattern will be in the string before you break that pattern), then you can get pretty far [here](https://regex101.com/r/pO0bC4/2). [Here](https://regex101.com/r/pO0bC4/1) is your original regex.

```
([a-z])(\d*)\.?
```